# Date error on chart when datasource has 0 rows

Tags: vb.net, winforms, charts, dataset

I have a chart that displays some data selected from a sql table. In the x-axis it displays dates.
I have how ever found a little annoying bug. 
The program has a list of customers and if i click a customer i get some data about the customer. If the first customer I click does not have any rows, the dates on the x-axel gets messed up (41394,5 instead of 2013-05-05 for example). 
If i restart the program and select a customer that have rows it works perfect and I can then choose a customer with no data and then select a customer with data again the tha date is correct.

Edit: To be more clear; If i first choose a customer with 0 rows it get messed up dates, even if I later select a customer with >0 rows. But, if i select a customer with >0 rows first, i can later select customers with 0 rows, get a blank chart and if i then switch to a client with rows I get normal dates.

The code for creating the dataset looks something like this:

```
'Test function for diagram results, returns DATASET
Public Function GetDiagramData(ByVal OrgNr As String) As DataSet
    Dim Con As SqlCeConnection = DbConn()
    Con.Open()
    Dim Com As New SqlCeCommand("SELECT Value1, Value2, Value3, Created AS Date FROM Information WHERE OrgNr = @orgnr ORDER BY Created DESC", Con)
    Com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orgnr", OrgNr)

    Dim da As New SqlCeDataAdapter(Com)
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    da.Fill(ds, "Diagrams")

    Con.Close()
    Com = Nothing

    Return ds
End Function
```

And this is the code that populates the chart:

```
Private Sub LoadDataForDiagrams()
    'TESTING
    Form1.Chart1.Series("Value1").YValueMembers = "Value1"
    Form1.Chart1.Series("Value1").XValueMember = "Date"
    Form1.Chart1.Series("Value1").BorderWidth = 4

    Form1.Chart1.Series("Value2").YValueMembers = "Value2"
    Form1.Chart1.Series("Value2").XValueMember = "Date"
    Form1.Chart1.Series("Value2").BorderWidth = 4

    Form1.Chart1.Series("Value3").YValueMembers = "Value3"
    Form1.Chart1.Series("Value3").XValueMember = "Date"
    Form1.Chart1.Series("Value3").BorderWidth = 3

    Dim SQL As New SQLCompact
    Dim Binding As DataSet = SQL.GetDiagramData(Form1.LBL_Client_ORG.Text)
    Form1.Chart1.DataSource = Binding.Tables("Diagrams")
    SQL = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Amagerd. After playing around in the settings for series i found the value "XValueType" for each member in the series. It was on "auto" per default and when i changed it to date it works just perfect. So thats the (really simple) soultion. Set them graphically here or add these line to the above code (part 2 of code):

```
Form1.Chart1.Series("Value1").YValueMembers = "Value1"
Form1.Chart1.Series("Value1").XValueMember = "Date"
Form1.Chart1.Series("Value1").BorderWidth = 4
Form1.Chart1.Series("Value1").XValueType = vbDate

Form1.Chart1.Series("Value2").YValueMembers = "Value2"
Form1.Chart1.Series("Value2").XValueMember = "Date"
Form1.Chart1.Series("Value2").BorderWidth = 4
Form1.Chart1.Series("Value2").XValueType = vbDate

Form1.Chart1.Series("Value3").YValueMembers = "Value3"
Form1.Chart1.Series("Value3").XValueMember = "Date"
Form1.Chart1.Series("Value3").BorderWidth = 3
Form1.Chart1.Series("Value3").XValueType = vbDate
```